# Pop-up contact form accessed globally from different pages jQuery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a little pop-up contact form but unfortunately, once I copy it and paste elsewhere on the website (even same page), only one of the forms works, the second one does not open on click at all. I cannot spot the error...
I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

JS code

```
   $(function() { 
     $('.contact').click(function () {
     $('#contactForm').fadeIn();
   })

   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
       var container = $("#contactForm");

   // when clicked out of the 'form window' it will fade out
   if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
   {
   container.fadeOut();
   }
   });
});
```

And also my HTML

```
 <div class="contact">Contact</div>

       <div id="contactForm">

         <h1>Interested?</h1>
         <small>Get in touch and I will respond as quick as possible!</small>

         <form class="centerform" action="#">
           <input placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
           <input placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
           <input placeholder="Subject" type="text" required />
           <textarea placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
           <input class="formBtn" type="submit" />
           <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
         </form>
       </div>
```

Comment: You have to use the same id once per context, have you tried changing the id when you paste it, for instance, in the same page?

Comment: Are you duplicating IDs? IDs **must** be unique

Comment: If I want to access exactly the same 'contact form' just from different page do I need to change the ID? That would mean that I have to make 'x' contact forms for 'x' pages right? How about making one that will work globally on the whole website? Assume that you have the main page with 'contact' button, then about us with 'contact' button again, both should pop up same contact form.

Comment: So I assume the only way to make it work is to create a new form on every page with different ID and change the JS script to pick up 'dynamic ID' of form? Thanks guys but I still wonder if it is possible to do it the way I wanted... like a 'one global contact form'. I hope my explanation is clear.